# When is the "requests" module removed from Python by default?

Tags: python

Previously, I remember "requests" module was included in Python by default, I use it a lot and it is quite convenient, but seems in newer versions it is no longer the case. I wanted to know from which version was it removed and why?

Answer (score 7):

The [`requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests) module is third-party code and it was never included in Python by default.  You're remembering incorrectly.